# Express checkout is not returning to website (currently in sandbox)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I don't use paypal all the time but I have a wordpress plugin I built to handle some basic payments.  I have started to implement this plugin on a new site and new paypal account and am running into some issues.  I am using a technique very similar to the selected answer in this post: [Easier way to integrate PayPal express checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626831/easier-way-to-integrate-paypal-express-checkout) (that's me, actually).

I'm not sure if there was a change with Paypal that is affecting the redirect after payment but I am setting the return, notify, etc url's in the form before passing it off to Paypal.  I have tried to match up the settings with the other paypal accounts I use this plugin with but the "Profile" page on Paypal seems *much* different on this new account (? did it change, maybe I signed up for the wrong type of account or have a settings misaligned).  I know one obvious solution would be to enable the auto return url within the profile page but my other Paypal accounts do not have this option enabled and also when I attempt this it does not help.

I am also having trouble locating the proper settings for changing the shop name (currently showing my email address) on the Paypal checkout page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sandbox settings are not tied to account settings at all, I just needed to make the changes when logged into sandbox.paypal.com when I was making them on paypal.com only..  Maybe this will help someone else in the future. Feel free to delete.